# Replace first word with sed keeping whitespace alignment

Tags: sed, replace, whitespace

I am trying to write a Shell script to edit an input file. Data is structured in the input file as follow:

```
1000␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣: final time
1000            : print time
0.1             : time step
```

The alignment is made with whitespaces as emphasized in the first line.
I am currently using `sed` to replace the parameters (first "word" of each line).

I couldn't find a way to do it without messing the alignment of the labels. I'm open to any suggestions, I don't particularly want to achieve this with `sed`. It is possible to change the structure of the input file by using tabs for example.

Here's an example of what I would like the script to do:

```
input file
----------
1000␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣: final time
1000            : print time
0.1             : time step
```

```
running the script
------------------
$ script --final-time=100
```

```
input file after running the script
-----------------------------------
100␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣: final time
1000            : print time
0.1             : time step
```

The length of the replacement string is not know in advance. It's not fixed and can be up to 6 characters.

Comment: You could look into `column`.

Comment: @BenjaminW interesting program. I'll have a look, thanks.

Comment: To get more specific help, maybe add a self-contained complete example of assigning a value to `replacement` and what the file should look like before and after the change, see [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
awk -v value="100" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" : "} $2=="final time" {$1=sprintf("%-15s",value)}1' file
```

Output:

```
100             : final time
1000            : print time
0.1             : time step
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/final time/{s/.*/\n&\n100/;:a;s/\n[^:](.*\n)(.)/\2\n\1/;s/\n[^:](.*\n)$/ \n\1/;ta;s/\n//g}' file
```

In overview, replace the first field by the replacement value a character at a time, making sure to overwrite the original value by spaces if the replacement string is shorter.

If the line contains the required match, prepend a newline to the start of the pattern space and a newline followed by the required replacement string to the end of the pattern space.

Within a loop: if the first character following the first newline is not a colon `:` i.e. the character which denotes the separation of the first field to the second, replace it by the first character following the second newline and replace the first newline after the replacement character. If there are no characters  following the second newline and the first character following the first newline is neither a space or a colon, replace it by a space and again shuffle the first newline. Otherwise, the replacement has been successful and remove all introduced newlines.